# Show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^{-\ln x} = 0$ without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How can I formally show that the following limit is $0$?
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^{-\ln x}$$ (Without using l'Hopital's rule.)

I can write it as
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x^{-\ln x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} e^{-\ln x \ln x}.$$
I would somehow need to argue that $ - \ln x \ln x \rightarrow -\infty$ as $x \rightarrow 0^+$.

Comment: As $x \downarrow 0$, $\ln x \to -\infty$, so $(\ln x)^2 \to \infty$, so $-(\ln x)^2 \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the last part of your argument, informally, you can note that $\ln x \to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$. Then you have

$$-(-\infty \cdot -\infty) = - (\infty) = -\infty$$

Comment: Or even *formally* if phrased in terms of limit forms. Or better, if you use the extended real numbers, and the fact the (continuous extension of) the logarithm is continuous on $[0,+\infty]$.

Comment: Ah, nice thinking. That was actually what I was thinking once I thought about this for a few minutes. My original answer was rushed as I was just about to leave for class.